¿Wget protege las contraseñas que viajan por internet?
Quiero descargar unas imágenes de una galeria y necesito autenticarme y mirando en el manual en pdf de wget aparecen estas opciones

‘--user=user’ ‘--password=password’ Specify the username user and
password password for both ftp and http file retrieval. These
parameters can be overridden using the ‘--ftp-user’ and
‘--ftp-password’ options for ftp connections and the ‘--http-user’ and
‘--http-password’ options for http connections.

Pero en el apartdo de seguridad dice:

When using Wget, you must be aware that it sends unencrypted passwords
through the network, which may present a security problem

¿Significa eso que cualquiera puede ver mi contraseña, incluso alguien fuera de mi red privada?
Aquí está el manual:
https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.pdf

Y por qué no iban a poder?? Es la misma razón por la que no se recomienda usar http para páginas web, si no siempre https, porque los datos privados sobre protocolo http son siempre visibles, nada viaja encriptado. Lo mismo al usar FTP en vez de SFTP. Si la URL que usas con wget va sobre https (o sftp), no hay problema. Al final WGET solo es una utilidad que hace una llamada a la url indicada, si la url utiliza un protocolo seguro, será segura. Por cierto, es recomendable usar --ask-pasword en vez de ponérsela en texto claro :)

@Benito-B probablemente quisiste decir FTPS (FTP/SSL/TLS), en vez de SFTP. Este último no es un FTP como tal, es un protocolo basado en SSH (puerto 22).

Correcto el protocolo que quería mencionar es FTPS :)

@Benito-B como dice "you must be aware that it sends unencrypted passwords through the network" entendí que enviaba las contraseñas sin encriptar independientemente del protocolo de aplicación usado. Gracias por despejarme las dudas :)
